Multi class image classification: Yolov8 much higher recall than Resnet (PyTorch)
I'm trying to do multi class image classification of wood veneer defects. I have 11 classes with 60-150 images per class. (Quite difficult problem since there isn't much data).
As reference I tried Yolov8 and Roboflow 2.0:
Yolo and Roboflow report a recall per class between 0.5 - 0.7. (validation data)
When I'm trying to train a model with the exact same data in PyTorch with Resnet 50.
My validation recall isn't getting higher than 0.1 and the model is overfitting (since training recall goes to 100%).
The code:
model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, len(class_names))  # Aanpassen aan het aantal klassen

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = model.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs=25):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}')
        print('-' * 10)

        for phase in ['train', 'val']:
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()
            else:
                model.eval()

            running_loss = 0.0
            running_corrects = 0

            for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)

                optimizer.zero_grad()

                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                    outputs = model(inputs)
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

                    if phase == 'train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)

            epoch_loss = running_loss / dataset_sizes[phase]
            epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / dataset_sizes[phase]

            print(f'{phase} Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f} Acc: {epoch_acc:.4f}')

    return model


model = train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs=25)

Is this a limitation of PyTorch & Resnet or am I doing something wrong?

It sounds to me like it's significantly overfitting, as you've suggested. One way of controlling this is to limit the number of parameters the model is allowed to vary. For example, initially you could freeze all the weights except the new output layer, and see whether that results in less overfitting. I think it'd be something like for param in model.parameters(): param.requires_grad = False; and then for param in model.fc.parameters(): param.requires_grad = True. That would result in all parameters being frozen except the new output layer.

Maybe you can use a pretrained model and then fine tune it

Double check what's coming out of your dataloader. Make sure you're using the full dataset and every batch is different. Second, since you're using a pretrained model, you don't want to train the full model (at least initially). Your untrained model.fc layer is going to backprop bad signal to the pre-trained layers. You want to first train just the new layer, then train the full model end to end using a lower learning rate for the pre-trained layers. If you still have issues with overfitting, look into data augmentation and regularization (weight decay, dropout)
